# Decide Solr facet names from dynamic fields

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search

I am after creating a web app where I would have to use dynamic fields to create facets, smilimar to pricegrabber.com.

I am not sure if pricegrabber decides the facet names or publishers ? How do we decide there will be a "Color" facet in case of microwave http://www.pricegrabber.com/appliances/microwave-ovens/p-528/  and a "resolution" facet in case of plasma/LCD http://www.pricegrabber.com/electronics/plasma-lcd-televisions/p-197/

What's the easiest way to handle such situations?

Comment: When you say dynamic fields, do you mean like [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Dynamic+Fields)?

Comment: @Srikanth, yes that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way do it. Assign a category to each product and a set of properties to each category. (The category to property mappings can be stored somewhere outside of Solr, for example, in a DB.)

The properties are your dynamic fields - `property_*` below. For example:

```
{
 product_name: Brand A 3 Cu. ft. microwave,
 category: 1,
 price: 45.35,
 property_color: Red,
 property_capacity_cu_ft: 3,
 property_brand: Brand A
}, 
{
 product_name: Brand B 45 inch plasma TV,
 category: 2,
 price: 4500.35,
 property_resolution: 1920 x 1200,
 property_aspect_ratio: Widescreen,
 property_brand: Brand B
}
```

Also, assign a category to each one of your auto-suggest keywords. For example, `microwave oven` could be mapped to `category` 1. When someone searches for `microwave oven` you pull in the properties of the category it belongs to i.e.

```
color
capacity_cu_ft
brand
```

and form your query like:

`q=microwave%20oven&facet=true&facet.query=property_color&facet.query=property_capacity_cu_ft&facet.query=property_brand`

(Here you may want to range facet for capacity_cu_ft though.)

If the user were to search a term not in your auto-suggest dictionary, then your best bet is to actually facet on the categories themselves. (Guess this is what pricegrabber does.) Of course, price is always available, so that is a facet you can always use on all searches.